# TS2559: Type string has no properties in common with type Object

Tags: typescript, dictionary, inheritance

In typescript, I have a map defined such as below which I want to accept (key, value) pairs of (string, anything).

```
let map= new Map<String, Object>()
```

when I try to insert a (key, value) pair to the map with a code that looks like below:

```
map.set("name", "someName");
```

I get this error `TS2559: Type  string  has no properties in common with type  Object`. I guess String does not inherit from Object here.

What is the best way to do this in typescript?

This would pass in Java.

Comment: You missed something important: *what are you trying to do*? Sure this would pass in Java because there are no primitive strings in Java. Only objects. But what do you want this map in TS to accept - strings, or just *anything*?

Comment: [Don't use those types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-files/do-s-and-don-ts.html#number-string-boolean-symbol-and-object).  Presumably you want `Map<string, {}>` or maybe `Map<string, unknown>` depending on what you're actually trying to support for the property type.  Your intuitions from Java will only go so far.  What is the use case for this map? Please [edit] to clearly describe it.

Comment: Please search Stack Overflow (and the web) for an error message before asking about it. For instance a [search on `TS2559`](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=TS2559) resulted in 56 matches here on Stack Overflow, and "About 4,700 results" [on Google](https://www.google.com/search?q=TS2559) when I looked for it.

Comment: I heartily recommend you go over [the basics of TS](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/intro.html), if you have to ask how to type "string" and "anything" and you don't know of either `string` or `any` (or better - `unknown`).

Comment: So then you're looking for `Map<string, unknown>`. Does that meet your needs? If so I could write up an answer (but there's not much to it). If not, what am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

`String` and `Object` types refer values on "heap", it is same as Java.
However, in TypeScript, the type of string literals are `string`. `String` refers objects, and `string` refers "primitive values". For more information, MDN published [article in detail](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String#string_primitives_and_string_objects).

`Object` is defined as follows (you may not understand its signature, but don't worry it - that is not relevant):

```
interface Object {
    constructor: Function;
    toString(): string;
    toLocaleString(): string;
    valueOf(): Object;
    hasOwnProperty(v: PropertyKey): boolean;
    isPrototypeOf(v: Object): boolean;
    propertyIsEnumerable(v: PropertyKey): boolean;
}
```

(I assume you are familar with Java's `interface`, so I will omit what `interface` is)

On the other hand, `string` has following members:

- index signature of number which is similar to `charAt(int)` method in Java,
- `Symbol.iterator`, which is mostly identical to `CharSequence`'s `codePoint` method in Java,
- and various methods that is named by `string`s

---

TypeScript is going on "structural typing", which is not same as Java (Java's type system is "nominal typing").
A major difference between those type systems is that structural typing judges sub-typing by type's property. Other words, `Hello` and `Hi` is same type in TypeScript's view as opposed to Java:

```
interface Hello {}

interface Hi {}

const hello: Hello = {};
// no compile errors
const hi: Hi = hello;
```

TypeScript sees intersection set of property to test if the value can be assignable and/or be able to pass. But, `Object` and `string` does not have common property at all! TypeScript complains about it to indicate that it is not what you may not wanted to be.

You can fix it by changing `String` to `string` as other users suggestion.